# Issue with MinTTY/MSYS2/bash and sbt showing control characters / no rich text output

Tags: sbt, msys2, mintty, terminal-color

A recent update (of either MinTTY/MSYS2/bash or sbt) started breaking the output of sbt such that control characters are appearing instead of displaying rich text output in the terminal:

[image]

From the image you can see that rich text does still work as can be seen from my prompt line, but sbt started showing control characters like `←[0m[`.

I'm on windows 11 and it was working perfectly fine last week, and my `TERM` terminal setting is set to `xterm`.

After some searching, I found these two posts:

- https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/13279
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-247532

both suggesting that I should try setting my `TERM` to `cygwin` but this did not solve the issue.

**Question**

1. How can I isolate where the issue is happening? I highly suspect it's an internal sbt update because the version it's indicating is `1.6.0` but the version I installed was `1.4.4` last year. I just tried uninstalling it and installing `1.6.2` via the installer but the issue still persists.
2. Does anyone have a solution to this issue? Is it a general thing that affects certain CLIs? From the links above it looks like it used to impact gradle as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it was MinTTY or MSYS2 because an update of those fixed the issue.

Working version of MSYS2:

```
$ cat /proc/version
MINGW64_NT-10.0-19044 version 3.3.5-341.x86_64 (@WIN-MG5BEJ9M9JD) (gcc version 11.3.0 (GCC) ) 2022-07-08 09:41 UTC
```

and MinTTY:

[image: mintty version]